# Line Code fails to execute until event "drop" is finished

Tags: jquery, windows, electron

Tools: JQuery, Node.js, Electron, Windows

Using JQuery I attach a function to be executed on "drop" event.

```
area.on("drop", {"extensionHandler":extensionHandler, "dropHandler":dropHandler}, onDragDrop).bind(this);

function onDragDrop(evt){
    if( !isValidDragDrop(evt) )
        return;

     loading.show(); <----- THIS LINE is the problem

     var validExtension = evt.data.extensionHandler;
     var fileListHandler = evt.data.dropHandler;

     var filesDragged = evt.dataTransfer.files.length;

      //Treat dragged files
      //....
      // more code....

     loading.hide();    
 };
```

It's the `loading.show()` line that won't get executed until all the files are done and over with. It's supposed to make a gif (loader) visible so the user doesn't think the app went haywire while processing the 20+ files they dragged over. The think is, it's like the line won't get executed until the whole function is finished, because the gif never shows. If I do a `console.log()` same thing happens. First all files get processed then the log occurs. I'm at a loss.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `loading.show()` won't work until `function onDragDrop(evt)` is **finished**. So I looked at the code and isolated the part that takes the longest and does the most processing. I took that part and placed it in a separate function and called it asynchronously (someone correct me if I am wrong for calling it that) with **setTimeOut**.

```
function onDragDrop(evt){
   if( !isValidDragDrop(evt) )
       return;

    loading.show(); <----- THIS LINE is the problem

    var validExtension = evt.data.extensionHandler;
    var fileListHandler = evt.data.dropHandler;

    var filesDragged = evt.dataTransfer.files.length;
    ......

    setTimeout(function(){ heavyLoad(filesDragged, fileListHandler); }, 10);    
 };
```

That's it. Now the **loader spinning gif** shows up since the **onDragDrop** event finishes completely. The **heavyLoad(...)** is obviously in charge of doing `loading.hide();` when it's done.